# C-shell: print result from row to column

Tags: shell, awk, scripting, csh

I have outputs:

```
1 rpt 4 qor 5 are 6 oip
```

I want it to become :

```
1 rpt
4 qor
5 are
6 oip
```

This is my code:

```
set d = `sort "04.txt" | uniq -c`
echo $d
```

Comment: Please revert your recent changes done in your question. This is completely different from your base question. You should open new posts for new questions, please revert it to your original question. Else answers given here doesn't make sense then, thank you.

Comment: I have changed your question to original one now, for new question please open a new post, thank you.

Comment: [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146936/print-total-amount-file-which-have-the-same-extension-in-c-shell#comment118693156_67146936) - don't write csh scripts. If this was a bourne shell your problem would simply be that you removed the standard quotes from your `echo` argument (see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). With csh, idk and it's not worth exploring.

Comment: @DongDao: [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) could be a good tool for that. You need to spend hours to **read documentation of `gawk`** ; see also [sort(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and [uniq(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) and the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). Read also  [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: Please post a new question about whatever it is you're trying to do (as opposed to how you're trying to do it) starting with raw input rather than the output from some previous phase you've implemented and ending with the final output you want and then we can help you do whatever that is the right way (which will definitely not be a csh script!).

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
xargs -n 2 < Input_file
```

***From `man xargs`:***

> -n max-args, --max-args=max-args Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size
> (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless  the -x option is given, in
> which case xargs will exit.

Comment: please help me in detail. i dont have Input_file

Comment: @DONGDAO, I have added details from man page of xargs in answer too.

Comment: The OPs input is almost certainly already on separate lines, they just aren't quoting the arg to echo and so the shell is removing the newlines and so they **think** their input is all on 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

```
akshay@sys:~$ cat file 
1 rpt 4 qor 5 are 6 oip

akshay@sys:~$ sed 's/ /\n/2; P; D'  file 
1 rpt
4 qor
5 are
6 oip

akshay@sys:~$ awk -v n=2 '{for (i=n+1; i<=NF; i+=n) $i = "\n" $i}1'  file
1 rpt 
4 qor 
5 are 
6 oip

akshay@sys:~$ awk -v RS=" " '{$1=$1; ORS=NR%2?FS:"\n" }1'  file 
1 rpt
4 qor
5 are
6 oip
```

Comment: please help me a new problem

Comment: @DONGDAO, Please revert your recent changes done in your question. This is completely different from your base question. You should open new posts for new questions, please revert it to your original question. Else answers given here doesn't make sense then, thank you.

Comment: The OPs input is almost certainly already on separate lines, they just aren't quoting the arg to echo and so the shell is removing the newlines and so they **think** their input is all on 1 line.

Comment: @Ed Morton you're right, since OP didn't explain more on his requirements, I just gave possibilities for the given input.